# Vulnerability scanning on target Android device

Tags: android, nmap, vulnerability-scanners, cve, nse

Is there an nmap vulnerability scanning script (vuln, vulscan, nmap-vulners etc) for scanning target Android devices on the network?

If not, is there any specific scanning tool that scans for CVE on target Android devices?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you looked at existing Android scripts?..

Comment: @sirMuffington I did Google search but nothing turned up.

Comment: Does this help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452599/mobile-device-identification-using-nmap

Comment: Unless the Android device has specifically been set up to run as some kind of server, there probably won't be any open ports to find.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

Google provide the STS SDK (Security Test Suite SDK):
https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/sts-sdk
...but this is "only" to develop *your own* security tests.

Whereas if you're a Google partner (e.g. an OEM making Android devices, with a partnership with Google), you have the full blown STS, with the automated tests to check that the CVE from Google Android monthly Security Bulletins have been indeed fixed.

Both the STS SDK and the Google partners STS leverage on adb (Android Debugger Bridge) as an agent on the Android device: https://developer.android.com/tools/adb